# How do you get the IP address of a Loki Service Node on the network?

Tags: monero-forks, loki, service-node

Is there a way to see the IP address of a Loki service node that is on the network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On any loki node regardless if its a service node or not, you can run the following command:

```
curl -sX POST http://localhost:22023/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_service_nodes"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' | grep -B 4 SERVICE_NODE_ID_HERE
```

Change localhost if your connecting to a remote loki node and change SERVICE NODE ID to the id you are looking for.